# is there a Video for writing to plist in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, plist

I'm not saying I'm lazy (I am), but I want to read what is in the plist, and then when the user does something, to append that info to the existing plist, and write it back, so that info is not lost.

Now that's the type of thing I would think there'd be a video on.

Thus, my question is twofold:

a) Where's a good video (iTunes, Standford Univ, iOS App Pgming Guide) on writing to a plist using file handlers ?(gulp)
b) how can I do a search and restrict the media to videos (so I can find videos on these subjects in the future)?
I'm especially looking for how to handle the notorious first time, and how to make sure I don't overwrite good data by wrongly thinking it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of such tutorials on YouTube. Have a look at this one: 
    [iPhone Programming - Reading/Writing .plist Files](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Oy-evy2xD8)