# Storing variables in property list files Cocos2d

Tags: variables, cocos2d-iphone, plist, store, retain

I am programming a cocos2d game where, in most games, you must complete the level previous to proceed on to the next level. Each level is in a different layer (node). I wanted to store integers (1-20) to the property list so the variables are retained throughout the entire game. And yes i have been searching the internet for about an hour and cant find anything.

I found a code to store variables but I don't know how to use it correctly.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"levelscompleted.save"];


    NSMutableDictionary* myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


    myDict = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];
    NSString *nssLevelsCompleted = [myDict objectForKey:@"LevelsCompleted"];
    LevelsCompleted = [nssLevelsCompleted intValue];

    LevelsCompleted = 445;


    [myDict setObject:nssLevelsCompleted forKey:@"LevelsCompleted"];



    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:myDict toFile:path];
```

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732405/is-there-a-video-for-writing-to-plist-in-ios

Comment: my code keeps returning (null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some sample code to get an idea (uses ARC for memory management):

```
- (NSString*) filePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectory,@"myfile.plist"];
    return filePath;
}

- (void)writeScoreToPlist:(NSInteger)score level:(NSString*)level {
    NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self filePath]];    
    if(plistDict==nil){
        plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];    
    }
    [plistDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:score] forKey:level];
    [plistDict writeToFile:[self filePath] atomically: YES];
}

- (NSInteger)readScoreFromPlist:(NSString*)level {
    NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self filePath]];
    NSNumber *value = [plistDict objectForKey:level];
    return value.integerValue;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [self writeScoreToPlist:999 level:@"Level1Highscore"];
    NSInteger score = [self readScoreFromPlist:@"Level1Highscore"];
    NSLog(@"Achieved score for level 1: %d",score);

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Output:

```
2012-01-29 16:24:30.844 plistTest[23531:f803] Achieved score for level 1: 999
```

Comment: when i save my variable in one layer and try and read it in the log using NSLog 'NSLog(@"Value: %@", value);' it comes back '(Value: null)'

Comment: There was a typo in the code, of course the dictionary must be initialized like this:  NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
Try out the edited sample code. Now it should work.

Comment: What if i wanted to set the value in writeToPlist to an NSString, How would i do that? with    [plistDict setValue:FinalScore forKey:@"Level1_HighScore"]; i get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. FinalScore is an NSString.

Comment: See my edited answer, but really you should invest some of your own effort to solve such problems. EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurs whenever you try to access a variable which has been deleted.